# Directly interrogating video card to confirm spec?

Tags: graphics-card, benchmarking, hardware-detection

I just bought a ASUS OEM Radeon R9 370 second-hand online and I'm not sure if it's okay or not.

I probably have no reason to suspect anything wrong, the labels look fine, except that I just benchmarked it (Passmark PerformanceTest 9) - and it's way *way* below spec on some points, in a way that I've been told is not typical or a bell curve.

In the system benchmarking results, almost everything is *90th percentile plus* and those that aren't are mostly 75th percentile plus. That's probably about right, because it's a heavy duty hexacore workstation with fast RAM, so CPU, memory etc are rated 97%+ (the card isn't held back by the baseboard/CPU). The graphics average around 60 - 80% because this isn't a top notch graphics card, and that's fine. But a few of the graphics benchmarks are just jawdropping bad compared to the rest, like *25th percentile minus* compared to other cards of the same kind.

In checking why this might be, I noticed that it's identified as a "Radeon R9 270" not 370 in the benchmarking suite as well as an "R9 200 series" in Windows Device Manager. The two cards (R9 270 and R9 370) seem to have almost identical specs on paper.

I asked on the Passmark forums about the Direct2D benchmark I was getting. The site owner is helpful - he checked and replied that when he looked, he found that this specific card has unusual benchmarks for Direct2D - some cards grouped very low (10fps), others grouped very high (55fps) - not in a usual bell curve. He didn't suggest what might cause that, but a misidentification of the card might do so (if there are 2 very different cards but they get reported as the same model, or a significant BIOS update applied only to cards after a given date, for example)

The main difference on the spec sheet between the 370 and 270 is the core clock, and this card reports 925 MHz which is more common in the R9 270 than the 370.

The difficulty is that it's an OEM product and the specs are almost identical between the 370 and 270. I've used AMD's own tools, as well as GPU shark and GPU-Z, but I suspect part of the problem may be that they are reporting data in their own database. If they (or any benchmarking software, or the card or driver) mis-identify the card, then they'll report the data they hold, or other incorrect data, not the data for the actual card.

For example the tools report the card BIOS as dated 2013, 2 years before the R9 370 came out. But that's not definitive - it uses the same GPU as the R9 270 which came out some time earlier, so I can't tell if it's reading the date from the card or not.

Is there an easy way to directly interrogate the card for its hardware spec, BIOS date+version, and any other data for which there's a public API, and be sure it's the card's own responses (not some database) that I'm seeing?

**NOTE: To save time, be careful if checking the card data - it's the R9 370, *not* the R7 370 or anything else. Some sites confuse the two.**

Comment: What are the PCI IDs?